# Using windows identity to check users custom role using the .IsInRole method

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, roleprovider, principal

I have created an MVC application whereby the user is able to authenticate either via ADFS or Forms login and in both cases I have been able to use the User.IsInRole method to check my user table that has a roleID attribute which ties to a role table in my database. This is done by including the following section in my webconfig within :

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="MyInternal.Providers.MyProvider, MyInternal" connectionStringName="MyContext" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I am now trying to implement windows authentication and have managed to get the users domain login name etc but when trying to follow same steps as with other two authentication types I am unable to get the IsInRole to work.

How can I tie the User from my repository to the authentication user. Is there some sort of casts or something required? I think that this may have been done by the authentication in ADFS and Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using the following within my ViewModel:

```
this.UserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

            if (this.UserName.Contains("\\"))
            {
                string[] stringArray = this.UserName.Split(new Char[] { '\\' });
                this.UserName = stringArray[1];

                MyUser identity = userRepository.Get(u => u.Username == this.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
                HttpContext.Current.User = identity;
            }
```